# De 1 parámetro a 5 máximo, se debe de visualizar del número 1 al parámetro introducido

Tags: bash, shell-script

Quiero realizar un Shellscript con 1 parámetro mínimo y 5 parámetros de máximo, y debe visualizar el número de el primer número hasta ese determinado parámetro.
Hay una pregunta similar que hice, pero no entiendo ese código, y debo de realizarlo con blucles WHILE:

```
./prueba.sh 2 5

Valor 2: 1, 2   
Valor 5: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Espero que me podáis ayudar, ya que no sé exactamente como plantearlo.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# > 1 ] && [ $# < 5 ]
then
while [ $# > 1 ]
        $#++;
if [ $# < 5 ]
then
echo "Valor $# es $#"
        $#++;
fi
        fi
```

Comment: estás planteando muchas preguntas bastante genéricas en forma de ejercicios a resolver. Tanto para ti como para la plataforma, sería mucho más útil que plantearas preguntas sobre cosas específicas: cómo generar tal bucle, como recibir X parámetros, cómo imprimir un número de valores. Lo digo porque todo lo que comentas ya se te ha respondido en preguntas anteriores, solo que al ser también genéricas no parece que estés extrayendo las enseñanzas necesarias.

Comment: Es eso, pero es un código que no entiendo, además de que debo de hacerlo con while, sin for.